# ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I faced this problem from several days and it happens every week I am unable to understand the problem.

Sphinx automatically lost connection on production server.

> ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'

I am using

- thinking-sphinx (3.1.4)
- Rails 4.2.1
- ruby 2.0.0

My configuration file thinking_sphinx is -

```
   development:
     min_infix_len: 1
     bin_path: '/usr/bin'
     searchd_binary_name: 'searchd'
     indexer_binary_name: 'indexer'
     utf8: true
     max_matches: 10000
   staging:
     min_infix_len: 1
     bin_path: ''
     searchd_binary_name: ''
     indexer_binary_name: ''
     max_matches: 10000
   production:
     min_infix_len: 1
     bin_path: ''
     searchd_binary_name: ''
     indexer_binary_name: ''
     max_matches: 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of issue and resolved with 'reconnect: true' in database.yml not sure if this will solve this issue, but once you will set this option it is not transection safe so if working please do few research with this.

```
 in database.yml

 reconnect: true
```